# How to define @input with limited items in DOM

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to define an `@Input` type of `Enum` in `ts` file and user just can select only one of that enum items.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'sale-tree',
    templateUrl: 'sale-tree.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['sale-tree.component.css'],
})
export class SaleTreeComponent {
    @Input() businessDataTable: BusinessDataTableType;

    constructor() {
    }

}

export enum BusinessDataTableType {
    Category,
    SalesRegion,
    Address
}
```

This is my parent component:

```
<ng-template>
    <sale-tree [businessDataTable]="BusinessDataTableType.Address"</sale-tree>
</ng-template>
```

But when I decided to value `businessDataTable` I face with numerous items, while I want to see just these three items:

> ```
>     Category
>     SalesRegion
>     Address
> ```

Is there any way to limit input items to these three items?

Comment: take a look to https://netbasal.com/how-to-add-angular-component-input-validation-b078a30af97f

Comment: @Eliseo The link you have put here is talk about Validation while my problem is something else. I'm gonna declare an 'Enum' as input parameter and in parent component when I want to value this parameter just see items which I declare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following output is what I had looked for:

```
@Component({
            selector: 'sale-tree',
            templateUrl: 'sale-tree.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['sale-tree.component.css'],
        })
        const DataTableType = {
            Address: 'Address' as 'Address',
            Category: 'Category' as 'Category',
            SalesRegion: 'SalesRegion' as 'SalesRegion'
        }
        type DataTableType= (typeof DataTableType)[keyof typeof DataTableType];
        export {DataTableType};

        export class SaleTreeComponent {
            @Input() selectedBusinessDataTable: DataTableType;
            @Output() nodeClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

            constructor() {
            }

            btnNodeClick(event) {
                if (this.selectedBusinessDataTable === BusinessDataTableType.Address) {
                    // your code
                }
                this.nodeClick.emit(event.currentTarget.value);
            }
        }

        export enum BusinessDataTableType {
            Address = 'Address',
            Category = 'Category',
            SalesRegion = 'SalesRegion'

        }
```

By declaring input parameter like above, in parent component when you want to value `selectedBusinessDataTable` parameter you'll just see these three items:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should go for making `*.d.ts` file for your component.